# Drop downs not working on image carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

I have a image carousel that fades at:
[tahoe-luxury-properties](http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/indexv1.html)

I can't seem to get the drop down links at Squaw Valley.., Alpine Meadows.. to open

I have the navbar working independently at:
[Navigation Working](http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/navigation.html)

Where the drop downs with carets do open.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include jQuery before the Bootstrap script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```